# Spring Boot - AutoConfigure properties based on other properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using web Spring Boot 1.4.3 and creating a custom `@AutoConfigure` to set a bunch of properties.  It turns out many properties I set depend on one built-in Spring property: `server.port`.  Question: What's the best way to make my AutoConfigurers use this property if it exists, otherwise default to 9999?

Here's how I do it with a properties file:

```
    myapp.port = ${server.port:9999}
```

Here's how far I've gotten with AutoConfiguration:

```
@Configuration(prefix="myapp")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyAppProperties.class)
public class MyAppProperties {
    @Autowired
    ServerProperties serverProperties;

    Integer port = serverProperties.getPort() otherwise 9999?

}
```

I've thought about using `@PostConstruct` to do the logic but looking at Spring-Boot's autoconfigure source code examples, I don't see them doing this so it feels like a code smell.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't get an iterative autoconfiguration like the Java compiler's annotation passes. Have you tried using `@AutoConfigureAfter`?

Comment: `Integer port = serverProperties.getPort() != null?serverProperties.getPort():9999`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer the @Value annotation since Spring 3.x (I believe).

```
public class MyAppProperties {
    @Value("${server.port:9999}")
    private int port;
}
```

If you set `server.port` in `application.properties`, it'll use the value set in there. Otherwise, it'll default to 9999.

Comment: Oh and it's Spring Boot 1.4.3 not 4.3 (apologies if I sound like someone with OCD)

Comment: Thanks for notes on 4.3 Spring version comment - i updated it to 1.4.3.

Comment: I ended up using `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Autoconfigure` as I needed to do more complex logic in the setter than simply 9999, but given my original question this is best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out! The key was to expose my dependent properties using `@Bean` rather than `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProps.class)`.  Due to the order which Spring injects properties, using `@Bean` lets me default to the dependent `server.port` property while still letting `application.properties` file override it.  Full example:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="myapp")
public class MyProps {
    Integer port = 9999;
}

@AutoConfigureAfter(ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class)
public class MyPropsAutoConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private ServerProperties serverProperties;

    @Bean
    public MyProps myProps() {
        MyProps myProps = new MyProps();
        if (serverProperties.getPort() != null) {
            myProps.setPort(serverProperties.getPort());
        }
        return myProps;
    }
}
```

This enables 3 things:

1. Default to 9999
2. If `server.port` is not null, use that
3. If user specifies a `myapp.port` in an `application.properties` file, use that (Spring injects it after loading the `@Bean`)