# Spring boot how to pick externalized spring properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this configurations which needs to be used for a spring boot application.

```
server.port=8085
server.servlet.context-path=/authserver
#data source
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=<url>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

By default spring-boot picks up up the application.properties file located in src/main/resources/

I want to alter this path and direct spring boot to different application.properties file

I can achieve this using

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/another-location.properties
```

Is there any any alternative solution I can achieve this without passing args through command line?

I was using this

```
   @PropertySource("file:C:\Users\test\.test\test.properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring")
    public class Configuration {

        private String ddlAuto;

        private String url;

        private String username;

        private String password;

        private String driverClassName;
    }
```

in my Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Configuration.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

There after I tried executing the app commenting out all datasource properties in application.properties under src/main/resources/ 
But it keeps giving me the error mentioned bellow and application fails to start

I was referring this tutorial : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

but as it's mentioned I get this error when i start the spring boot application

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException:
```

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe your process has no permission to read the file? Could you paste full stack trace?

Comment: Can you put the `@PropertySource` annotation on a different bean? I'm not sure if it's picked up properly like this (as `Configuration` won't be a regular bean). The [documentation about externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) recommends to put these on a separate `@Configuration` class.

Comment: *Don't* embed a path to an externalized file in your code. It's extra work and makes actually using it a lot more difficult.

Comment: @Shenali Silva this might help you: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-configuration-properties-example/

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to have externalized properties is to use the spring.config.location system property, by starting your application like so:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=/path/to/my/file.properties app.jar
```

The reason for this is that you don't add coupling between your code and your filesystem hierarchy.

Before Spring Boot 2.0 this property is additive, meaning that it will complement the default locations. After Spring Boot 2.0, spring.config.location replaces the default locations (e.g. classpath src/main/resources/application.properties). To keep the additive behaviour after 2.0, use spring.config.additional-location instead.

Please see here for [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) on this matter.

Comment: Thanks for the spring.config.additional-location hint

Answer (score 0):

I am able to make it work properly on Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE. This is what I have done:
I have a `test.properties` in my `/tmp` folder with the following content:

```
test.myprop=hello
```

I also have the usual property file in the resources folder:

```
myprop=world
```

I have created a class for the custom property file:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/tmp/test.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class TestConfig {

    private String myprop;

    public String getMyprop() {
        return myprop;
    }

    public void setMyprop(String myprop) {
        this.myprop = myprop;
    }
}
```

And then in my main class I have enabled to configuration properties:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TestConfig.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Now I have this test controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Value("${test.myprop}")
    private String externalisedProp;
    @Value("${myprop}")
    private String prop;

    @GetMapping("test")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("externalised: " + externalisedProp);
        System.out.println("not externalised" + prop);
    }
}
```

Which, once called, is properly printing:

```
externalised: hello
not externalised: world
```

My `TestConfig` class is in the same package as the `MyApp` main class.
What I have done is very similar, almost identical, to your solution, are you sure your path is correct? Also, I can see that the content of your property file is not matching what you have in your config class, the prefix is different. Maybe that is the problem?

Edit:
I have tried to remove the `@Configuration` annotation from my property class (which you do not have as well) and it is not able to pick up the externalised properties anymore. The error is different though but you should try to add it.

Comment: prifix is 'spring' spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=<url>

Comment: Config class parameters are private String ddlAuto and private String url. what is wrong you find in there?

Comment: If the prefix is `spring` and the field in the class is named ddlAuto, in the property file you should have `spring.ddl-auto` and `spring.url` which you have not. I am not sure that is correct.

Comment: Check this, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538171/spring-boot-autoconfigure-properties-based-on-other-properties