# Spring boot Externalized properties with different folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

basically, what i want to do is

i have this structure in my spring boot folder

```
--conf
   --MyApplication-UAT.properties
   --MyApplication-PROD.properties
   --MyApplication-DEV.properties
   --MyApplication.properties
--src
   --main
      --java
      --resource
         --application.properties
   --test
--pom.xml
```

i want to set `spring.profiles.active` in `application.properties` and then if i set it to `DEV`, my code will take all properties from `MyApplication-DEV.properties`, if i set it to `UAT`, my code will take from `MyApplication-UAT.properties`

is it possible to do this in spring boot?

so far i already know if i put all properties in `resource/application-{profile}.properties`, it will work. but i want to externalized my configuration.

this is the example what i want to achieve, if i have `test.url="www.google.com"` in `MyApplication-DEV.properties` and `test.url=www.yahoo.com` in `MyApplication-UAT.properties`

and `spring.profile.active=DEV` in `application.properties`

if i run as java application in eclipse, the result of

```
@value(${"test.url"})
private String url;

System.out.println(url);
```

will be `www.google.com`

thank you.

Comment: Please use -Dspring.config.location to config resources

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot how to pick externalized spring properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413054/spring-boot-how-to-pick-externalized-spring-properties-file)

Comment: hi @NghiaDo , no. what i mean is, i want to run it on eclipse, like normal run java application without setting in cmd like that.

Comment: @pringi no., its different. i've already seen it. thank you

Comment: you can pass the same param via Eclipse or any IDE

Comment: @NghiaDo please see my edited post. thank you.

Comment: I suggest use the defaults. Rename folder to `config` place an `application-{profile}.properties` in there and it works out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

i found the way. i dont know if this is good or not, but it works.

```
public enum ProfileEnum {
    LOCAL("MyApplication-LOCAL.properties"),
    DEV("MyApplication-DEV.properties"), 
    UAT("MyApplication-UAT.properties");
    
    private String property;

    private ProfileEnum(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
}

public static String getProperties(String properties, String profile) {         
            String prop = null;
            String strClassPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "conf" + File.separator;
            String nameProp = ProfileEnum.valueOf(activeProfile).getProperty();
            strClassPath = strClassPath + nameProp;
            try { 
                FileInputStream reader = new FileInputStream(strClassPath);
                Properties p = new Properties();
                p.load(reader);
                prop = p.getProperty(properties);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            return prop;
        }
```

and then use this to get properties you need

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

    String url = Util.getProperties("test.url", env.getDefaultProfiles()[0]);
```